# Docker Twilio serverless:init doesn't work on host file system

Tags: twilio

Using the Docker version of Twilio, the command
`twilio serverless:init`
does not setup the directory structure on the host file system.

I can't run the Twilio CLI on my Centos 7 machine and that is why I'm using the Docker version.

I think that I could bind the host project directory to the container. Wondering if that is over-complicating the solution.

Also, commands like `twilio autocomplete bash` don't work either. Binding the user directory, in this case, seems like a  bit of a hack.

I'm beginning to wonder if anyone actually uses the Docker version for real development.

I just don't want to spin my wheels trying to make something work that really isn't cut out for what I need.

Setting up another workstation with a newer OS seems to be the only solution and that's a big deal for me.

Please correct me where I am wrong or suggest simple work-arounds.